# FeatureExtraction[] for Text -- to normalize text or not?

Tags: text, natural-language, nlp, machine-learning

The title pretty much captures my question.  When I use `FeatureExtraction[]` for text,

- should I normalize text before parsing it through `FeatureExtraction[]` or not or is text normalization (ToLowerCase, DeleteStopwords, WordStem) performed by `FeatureExtraction[]`?
- Is it possible to extract information or data from the intermediate steps within `FeatureExtraction[]`, viz.:

[image]

---

Here is a MWE with a made-up corpus.  `text1` is the original corpus while `text2` is the normalized version of the corpus.

For this corpus, normalizing the text leads to some of the text being exactly similar to others (as expected, I think since normalization gets rid of some "noise").

```
text1 = {"the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.", 
   "the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.  What a fox!", 
   "the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy fox.  What a good fox!", 
   "the quick brown fox.", "the fox is brown and quick.",
   "that is a waterfall."}; (*Original corpus*)
words = TextWords@DeleteStopwords@text1; (*Deletion of stop words*)
text2 = Table[
  StringJoin@Riffle[WordStem@words[[i]], " "], {i, 1, 
   Length@words}] ;(*Stemming of words and creation of normalized \
version of text*)
```

I train `FeatureExtraction` on both these corpora to create `fe1` and `fe2`.

```
fe1 = FeatureExtraction[
  text1, {"SegmentedWords", "TFIDF", 
   "StandardizedVector"} ] (*Feature Extraction applied to \
non-normalized text.*)
fe2 = FeatureExtraction[
  text2, {"SegmentedWords", "TFIDF", 
   "StandardizedVector"} ](*Feature Ext. applied to normalized text*)
```

An association is created to plot using `FeatureSpacePlot`:

```
assoc1 = AssociationThread[text1 -> features1];
assoc2 = AssociationThread[text2 -> features2];
```

The `FeatureSpacePlot` shows that the text clusters together in a **similar** fashion but not the *same*.

[image]

In other words,

- `"the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.", "the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.  What a fox!", "the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy fox.  What a good fox!"` are close to each other.
- `that is a waterfall` is separate from all the other text.
- `the quick brown fox` and `the fox is brown and quick` are close to each other.

Naturally, the `the quick brown fox` and `the fox is brown and quick` are on top of each other in the normalized text because of them being agnostic to order of words.